# Spring: multiple transactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing an application with spring boot and spring-data-jpa, where I have a method which does two things:

1. It saves into a database a list of elements, with a JpaRepository, so the method save is marked with @Transactional.
2. It refreshes a cache, so it performs a find all operation over the database with the same JpaRepository.

If one of the element of the list has an error (like a not permitted null value), I would like to rollback the save list operation and do not execute the find all query, but it is doing the find query and throwing the commit exception at this point.

I have try with different types of propagation policies but without any succeed.
Also I know I could take out the find query to an outer method, but for an encapsulation matter I would prefer to not do it.

Below you have the method:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public synchronized void saveMessageFilters(List<MessageFilter> list) {
    logger.debug("Insert or update message filters <{}>", list);
    for (MessageFilter filter : list) {
        checkIfMessageFilterExists(filter);
        MessageFilter messageFilter = messageFilterRepository.save(filter);
        logger.info("Message filter <{}> processed",messageFilter);
    }
    List<MessageFilter> messageFilters = (List<MessageFilter>)messageFilterRepository.findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA probably  flush the pending update operations before executing the findAll, that's what it trigger the error on the findAll method.

Just manually flush before executing the findAll should do the trick

```
messageFilterRepository.flush();
List<MessageFilter> messageFilters = (List<MessageFilter>)messageFilterRepository.findAll();
```

Comment: Anyway this change about nothing in terms of what's really executed against database because in practice the error is raised during the flush which is triggered before the select execution.